# Rest With Spring Java

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to link my Spring Bean with my Rest application but not able to do the same.
I have a simple User Pojo with id, name and profession
My UserDao is

```
public static List<User> getAllUsers(){ 
  List<User> userList = null;  
  userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
  ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
  User user=(User)context.getBean("hbean");
  userList.add(user); 
  return userList; 
}
```

My service call looks as follows

```
UserDao userDao = new UserDao();  
@GET 
@Path("users") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) 
public List<User> getUsers(){ 
  return userDao.getAllUsers(); 
}
```

This method is not working , i tried without Spring ( by just initializing constructor in UserDao then program works fine)

Even i tested same with this, and printed on console, it worked fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<User> userList = null;  
  userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
  ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
  User user=(User)context.getBean("hbean");
  userList.add(user); 
  userList.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

if the above code is working fine , then what might be the problem in my service call after deployment.

Comment: >This method is not working< - that's too generic...

Comment: Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring, you're most likely using the DI framework too. In your service, you have the following defined:

```
  UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
```

As this causes Spring not to be able to directly inject values and other dependencies to that object - it may cause errors. Might be a good idea to change that instansiation to:

```
  @Resource
  UserDao userDao;
```

This may solve your issue. If it does not - look in to the definition of `UserDao`. Is it annotated with e.g `@Service`, `@Component` or any other spring descriptive annotation? If so - check that your beans.xml actually includes configuration that implies classes defined in the package location that `UserDao` is defined are configured.

Comment: Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Comment: Try including spring-context to your classpath

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code. In no particular order:

```
User user=(User)context.getBean("hbean");
```

You do not define a bean called "hbean" anywhere in the code you've provided, and User should not be a bean either way.

```
public static List<User> getAllUsers()
```

Why is this method static? In most use cases your DAO will also be a bean injected by Spring.

```
 ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
```

Assuming you've already turned the DAO into a bean, you don't need to make another ApplicationContext, and this is generally done for you by either Spring Boot or the listener invoked by your servlet container.

```
UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
```

Is pointless, because the method you need is static, unless you've already made the changes I suggested above, in which case you'd probably do something like:

```
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
```

So I would suggest you start reading a few (older) Spring tutorials first, or just ditch everything you wrote and go for Spring Boot.

The following tutorials may be helpful:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext